# How use <FNC1 character> in Report Designer with UCC128

Tags: acumatica, barcode

I would like to edit the UCC 128 standard but I cannot put the FNC1 character.
What code should we use?

[image]

[image]

Comment: Some barcode libraries will do it for you. If you wish to get into the technical details, try reading up on [GS1-128 Symbology Specifications](http://www.gs1tw.org/twct/gs1w/download/GS_Section_5-3_V7.pdf)  and / or look at the source of [Project Zint](https://sourceforge.net/projects/zint/).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The version 22R2 update the GS1-218 function.
Now, it's OK.

Answer (score 1):

I think Acumatica support might have provided the lazy answer.  I agree the human readable does not appear to work but I do think it's possible to use the FNC1 character in a report.  Through some trial and error, I've found that when your Barcode Type is UCC128, using the standard open parenthesis "(" is interpreted as FNC1.

Use this value to reproduce the barcode in your example:

```
='(0203760164231722(3739'
```

From there, keep your picture box small enough to hide the Human Readable component and instead use your own text box, formatting as you'd like.

[image: Report Output with improper Human Readable]

Answer (score 0):

Report Designer is not compatible with GS1-218 (answer from ACUMATICA via JIRA)

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).